# How can I store 4 char into an unsigned int using bitwise operation?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I would like to store 4 char (4 bytes) into an unsigned int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to shift the bits of each char over, then OR combine them into the int:

```
unsigned int final = 0;
final |= ( data[0] << 24 );
final |= ( data[1] << 16 );
final |= ( data[2] <<  8 );
final |= ( data[3]       );
```

That uses an array of chars, but it's the same principle no matter how the data is coming in. (I think I got the shifts right)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using the `char` keyword in example code in C.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is bad. Fixed. :)

Comment: If `data` is a `signed char` array, `|=` and `<<` won't work as you want.

Comment: @Pascal:  Yes it will; left-shift of a signed type is well-defined.

Comment: @Clifford I'm not saying it's not well defined. I'm saying it doesn't do what the program needs. Try `char data[4] = {-12,57,33,-120};

main()
{
  unsigned int final = 0;
  final |= ( data[0] << 24 );
  final |= ( data[1] << 16 );
  final |= ( data[2] <<  8 );
  final |= ( data[3]       );
  printf("%x\n", final);
}`
on a compiler that has signed chars.

Comment: @Pascal: Doh! Of course. I suggest changing each `data[n]` reference to `(data[n] & 0xff)` to resolve char signed/unsigned ambiguity.

Comment: The union answer posted already is a much more readable solution.

Answer (score 4):

One more way to do this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
union int_chars {
    int a;
    char b[4];
};
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    union int_chars c;
    c.a = 10;
    c.b[0] = 1;
    c.b[1] = 2;
    c.b[2] = 3;
    c.b[3] = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple, its better :

```
/*
** Made by CHEVALLIER Bastien
** Prep'ETNA Promo 2019
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int x;
  char e = 'E';
  char t = 'T';
  char n = 'N';
  char a = 'A';

  ((char *)&x)[0] = e;
  ((char *)&x)[1] = t;
  ((char *)&x)[2] = n;
  ((char *)&x)[3] = a;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%c\n", ((char *)&x)[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (not bit-wise, but maybe more easy):

```
unsigned int a;
char *c;

c = (char *)&a;
c[0] = 'w';
c[1] = 'o';
c[2] = 'r';
c[3] = 'd';
```

Or if you want bit-wise you can use:

```
unsigned int a;
a &= ~(0xff << 24); // blank it
a |= ('w' << 24); // set it
// repeat with 16, 8, 0
```

If you don't blank it first you might get another result.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a cast, should it be c = (char *)&a?

Comment: That would be optional. I'll add it. Thanks